# Azure Web App request headers appended by Microsoft

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Does anyone know if any headers are added to the inbound request by the Azure infrastructure/host services? For Azure Websites and Azure Functions HTTP trigger.

For example, `X-Forwarded-For` or even the client's IP country?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a thing at all, you can check the request yourself. On my side, all I can see are Accept, Accept-Encoding, Cache-Control, Connection, Host, User-Agent, etc., but without those headers you said.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have to use Azure Front Door.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-http-headers-protocol

My understanding is that GCP adds a bunch of useful headers for free, since it costs nothing.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers